# wxWidgets - wxMenuBar's dropdown menu alignment is wrong

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am testing out wxWidgets and followed a hello world program from the Internet.

As soon as a run the program I notice that the dropdown menu of the main menu bar has incorrect alignment, shown in the screenshot below.

My OS is Windows 10.

Here is the code:

```
// wxWidgets "Hello world" Program
// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
class MyApp: public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
private:
    void OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
enum
{
    ID_Hello = 1
};
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(ID_Hello,   MyFrame::OnHello)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT,  MyFrame::OnExit)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_ABOUT, MyFrame::OnAbout)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame( "Hello World", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(450, 340) );
    frame->Show( true );
    return true;
}
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
        : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append(ID_Hello, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H",
                     "Help string shown in status bar for this menu item");
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append(wxID_EXIT);
    wxMenu *menuHelp = new wxMenu;
    menuHelp->Append(wxID_ABOUT);
    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append( menuFile, "&File" );
    menuBar->Append( menuHelp, "&Help" );
    SetMenuBar( menuBar );
    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText( "Welcome to wxWidgets!" );
}
void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close( true );
}
void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxMessageBox( "This is a wxWidgets' Hello world sample",
                  "About Hello World", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION );
}
void MyFrame::OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxLogMessage("Hello world from wxWidgets!");
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOuLv.jpg)

Comment: Have no idea about something from the Internet. Can you run the official "menu" or "minimal" samples from the wxWidgets and report back? Also what is your compiler? What version?

Comment: Does your system use an RTL locale by chance? I've never seen such a problem with the menus, but an RTL bug looks like the most likely explanation. Also, which version of wxWidgets do you use?